# Has anyone got a LyX 2 precompiled for Windows?

Tags: compiling, lyx, windows

I've been trying to compile LyX 2 myself but I can't start the resulting executable (the `Resources` directory is missing a lot of subdirectories). I don't know what the problem is, I exactly followed the instructions from the programmers. The last step, "compile the `INSTALL` project in MSVC" succeeds with 13 successful operations (and none failed). Does anyone know what the problem is or does someone maybe have a working executable that you could send to me (via Yousendit.com or similar)?

Comment: Are you using http://hotfile.com/dl/114106147/50313a2/LyX-2.0.0rc3-AltInstaller.zip.html?  It's been mentioned as working on lyx-users.

Comment: Hey thanks that could have been an answer! It worked. Before, I just dl'd the `.tar.gz` from ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.0/rc3/ and then followed the instructions in the `INSTALL.Win32` file from the archive. lyx-users is a mailing list? I'm not on it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a comment into an answer...

The `lyx-users@lists.lyx.org` mailing list is the first place to check if you have trouble getting recent releases to work.  Michal Skrzypek put together and tested an installer for the most recent Lyx release, Lyx-2.0.0rc3, and [announced it there](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg86174.html).

Lyx.org has [some general information about the Lyx mailing lists](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists).